# In eclipse, maven dependencies are overriding project dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a "master project" that uses several "modules".  The modules are in the pom.xml, but I also have the code for the modules as projects in Eclipse.  I defined the modules as project dependencies both in "Properties|Project References" and in "Properties|Java Build Path".  I also made sure all of the Eclipse projects are at the top of "Order and Export" in Java Build Path.

The master project is not recognizing changes to the modules within eclipse.  When I press F3 to see the code, it opens java source from my .m2 directory.  It's obviously ignoring my Eclipse projects.  Am I missing some setting?  What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to add the dependent projects into the Project references (at least when using m2eclipse-plugin), just add them as dependencies on your masters' pom.xml. I haven't had the need to touch the Build path since I've started using Maven in Eclipse.

Make sure you have enabled the Workspace resolution of the plugin by right clicking on project root -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution. If it says "Disable Workspace Resolution", it is already enabled. You may also need to run "Update project configuration" under the same menu.

This way when you run your master-project from within Eclipse, any changes made to the other projects will be "visible" to the master (and you can actually use hot swap during runtime even on the other projects).

Comment: Weird, both Enable and Disable Workspace resolution was on the menu of master project.  I clicked enable, it rebuilt, but now broke on some classes that actually exist in eclipse but not in maven.  I think something's really hosed.  Any more hints?

Comment: First try cleaning the entire workspace. If this does not help, instead of guessing what could be wrong in the different projects' configs, I'd suggest the following: create a new workspace from File -> Switch workspace -> Other, copy settings if necessary, then import all your projects to the new workspace using File -> Import... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects. Select Browse and navigate to the root of your old workspace and click Ok. Select all the poms and click Finish. Now you have a "clean" workspace with all the projects and hopefully the Workspace resolution working out-of-the-box.

Comment: This a great idea, but it didn't work.  The Master Project is in a different directory from the modules..do you think that breaks things?

Comment: It might be that Eclipse is still reading the project-settings from the project directories (.project-file, .settings-directory). You could try copying all the project directories minus the .project-files and .settings-directories to a single directory, and then import from there. That way you'll also still have the originals in case something goes wrong. I tried this copying all projects from one workspace that contains multiple dependent maven-projects to a new, empty workspace, then import and at least it worked with them (the dependencies were also resolved in the new workspace).

Comment: Make sure you have enabled the Workspace resolution of the plugin by right clicking on project root -> Maven -> Enable Workspace Resolution.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Maven, you pretty much want to commit to Maven.  Even if you do configure Eclipse with Eclipse-specific dependencies, anytime you update your project configuration using Maven, it will do a complete rewrite of your configuration.

I strongly recommend converting any of your other project build dependencies into Maven-enabled projects that can be used as Maven dependencies.

In your specific case (through using the Maven modules), this means ensuring that each of your modules are imported into Eclipse as m2e-enabled projects.  m2e will then automatically wire in the dependencies between modules and other dependent projects.

Answer (score 0):

Im scratching my head as to why you would need your modules defined as dependencies on your top level project. Are you trying to avoid having to define the (cross) dependencies at a module level? In any case, as per other suggestions, first of all put your dependencies in the correct places in your POM, then either run

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

to update your Eclipse settings, or better still, make sure [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) is installed and import your maven projects directly into the IDE.

Comment: The current plugin is called "m2e" and is available from the default update site.

Comment: m2e is an abbreviation for m2eclipse last time I checked Sonatype's website.

Comment: It's not a Sonatype project anymore, it's now an Eclipse project:
"Sonatype has completed the transition of the M2Eclipse project to Eclipse. 
Please go to this URL for M2E information: http://eclipse.org/m2e"

Comment: It means you have to search for "m2e" not "m2eclipse" in the install dialog and you don't have to specify a custom update site anymore.

Comment: Did you read that on the Sonatype M2Eclipse link I included. And did you notice the M2Eclipse logo at the top of the page you linked? These are great value-add comments!

Comment: -1. Have to second @Puce. m2eclipse from Sonatype ( where your link is pointing ) has been end-of-lifed and is no longer supported.